# Is there a way to intercept database output (dbms_output) with sql2o?

Tags: oracle, dbms-output, sql2o

I am using **sql2o** with **Oracle** database in a Java-based project. Often in my sql queries I use `dbms_output.Put_line('A message...')` in order to track what is going on.

Is there a way to intercept this output with sql2o so I can pass it on to my logs? Or perhaps there's an alternative to `dbms_output` which can do that?

Comment: You need to retrieve the output manually through the JDBC connection by   calling `dbms_output.get_line` through a `CallableStatement`

Comment: you can insert your logs to log table

Comment: The intercept will be in the same session where the query is executed? whether one session is executing the query and other session is dedicated to intercepting logs?

Comment: Alternative is to use dbms_pipe:
https://dioncho.wordpress.com/2009/11/10/logging-in-plsql/

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz Yes, the intercept is meant to be executed in the same thread as the query.

Comment: Thanks all! I'll try these tips and let you know what the result is.